# Dropdownlist Issue in Win browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, c#-4.0

Our application will run on Win browser with `IE11`, in `IE11` it's works fine but when I run this on `Winbrowser`, `Dropdown` Options width is less than the `dropdown` width.

Here is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvAYH.png)

I'm using this code.

```
< asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserInUSE" runat="server" width="100"> < /asp:DropDownList >
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You should worry only when the width is less than the content within the options. In your screenshot, I don't see anything wrong or any issues in user experience.

Comment: Thanks @Thangadurai but perviously it's working fine in Winbrowser compatible with IE8,recently we migrated to IE11. Even when I run this in IE11 also works fine,issue is only with winbrowser only. Is there any reason?